# how to get length if image exist in product_image 1 to 4 boject path using javascript

Tags: javascript

**In webservice 1 ike this**

```
                  "product_image1":"http://XYZ.co.uk/product_img/big/1_14238411703234.JPG" ,
                 "product_image2":"http://XYZ.co.uk/product_img/big/2_14238411703234.JPG" ,
                 "product_image3":"http://XYZ.co.uk/product_img/big/",  
                 "product_image4":"http://XYZ.co.uk/product_img/big/",
```

**In webservice 2 ike this**

```
"product_image1":"http://XYZ.co.uk/product_img/big/1_14303945253625.jpg" ,
                  "product_image2":"http://XYZ.co.uk/product_img/big/2_14303945253625.jpg" ,
                  "product_image3":"http://XYZ.co.uk/product_img/big/3_14303945253625.jpg",  
                  "product_image4":"http://XYZ.co.uk/product_img/big/4_14303945253625.png",
```

**My Code : -**

```
 items+='<img id="slideImgId3" src='+item.product_image1+' class="detailShowBigImg">';


                 items+='<img src='+item.product_image1+'  onclick="changeImage3(\''+item.product_image1+'\');" class="multiImgShow">';
                 items+='<img src='+item.product_image2+'  onclick="changeImage3(\''+item.product_image2+'\');" class="multiImgShow">';
                 items+='<img src='+item.product_image3+'  onclick="changeImage3(\''+item.product_image3+'\');" class="multiImgShow">';

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function changeImage3(img3)
  {
    document.getElementById("slideImgId3").src=img3;
  }
</script>
```

you can see webservice 1 And webservice 2. in webservice 1 there are product_image3 & product_image4 have no image and in webservice 2 all object images are there so how can resolve this problem and make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this set of code

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
//or however you get a handle to the IMG
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you knew the images are .jpg or .png,you can use Regular Expressions to do like this:

> ```
> var re=/\/([^\/]*?\.jpg)/i; 
> var str=new Array('www.iamgood.cn/images/111.jpg',
> 'www.iamgood.cn/images/',
> 'www.iamgood.cn/images/333.jpg');
> for (i=0;i<str.length;i++){
> var a =re.exec(str[i]); console.log(a);
> }
> ```
>
> output:
>
> ```
>  ["/111.jpg", "111.jpg", index: 21, input:"www.iamgood.cn/images/111.jpg"]
>  null
>  ["/333.jpg", "333.jpg", index: 21, input:"www.iamgood.cn/images/333.jpg"]
> ```

There you will get null with no image

Comment: if (item.product_image1 != "http://jXYZ.co.uk/product_img/big/") {
              items += '<img src=' + item.product_image1 + '  onclick="changeImage3(\'' + item.product_image1 + '\');" class="multiImgShow">';
            }  using this display only those images which have in full image path.